# AcquireTokenSilentAsync in iOS App not returning token

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, bearer-token, azure-ad-msal

**Context**

I have a Xamarin.Forms app which makes requests to an API using MSAL (Android and iOS version 1.1.4-preview0002). There are two pages which makes requests, and they are structured similarly. On Android, the requests always work, but in iOS, they always work on one page while on the other page, they usually don't work.

After debugging, I've found that it has to do  with AcquireTokenSilentAsync. Most of the time, it returns a token with a valid IdToken to be used as the Bearer token for my API requests e.g. when the user logs in or goes to the another page. But when I use it for the page that doesn't work, a timeout exception is raised:

```
{System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request ---> System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out.  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest+<RunWithTimeoutWorker>d__241`1[T].MoveNext () [0x000ba] in <63f1529d84e54d74ba92c4719d33184c>:0 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00018] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:1180   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic (System.IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2[T,TResult] endFunction, System.Action`1[T] endAction,System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] promise, System.Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x0000f] in <7d5a05cfcb09432d8cc656b9d781e54b>:0 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <7d5a05cfcb09432d8cc656b9d781e54b>:0   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>d__64.MoveNext () [0x003d3] in/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClientHandler.cs:402    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>d__64.MoveNext () [0x0046c] in/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClientHandler.cs:406 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <7d5a05cfcb09432d8cc656b9d781e54b>:0   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<SendAsyncWorker>d__48.MoveNext () [0x00080] in/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClient.cs:276 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <7d5a05cfcb09432d8cc656b9d781e54b>:0   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Http.HttpRequest+<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext () [0x00107] in <4e39820fa40244d9adbc367b93b1f942>:0 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <7d5a05cfcb09432d8cc656b9d781e54b>:0   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Http.HttpRequest+<ExecuteWithRetryAsync>d__4.MoveNext () [0x000aa] in <4e39820fa40244d9adbc367b93b1f942>:0 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <7d5a05cfcb09432d8cc656b9d781e54b>:0   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Http.HttpRequest+<SendPostAsync>d__1.MoveNext () [0x00081] in <4e39820fa40244d9adbc367b93b1f942>:0 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <7d5a05cfcb09432d8cc656b9d781e54b>:0   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.OAuth2.OAuth2Client+<ExecuteRequestAsync>d__9`1[T].MoveNext () [0x0014d] in <4e39820fa40244d9adbc367b93b1f942>:0 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <7d5a05cfcb09432d8cc656b9d781e54b>:0   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.OAuth2.OAuth2Client+<GetTokenAsync>d__8.MoveNext () [0x0007d] in <4e39820fa40244d9adbc367b93b1f942>:0 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <7d5a05cfcb09432d8cc656b9d781e54b>:0   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase+<SendHttpMessageAsync>d__41.MoveNext () [0x000b2] in <4e39820fa40244d9adbc367b93b1f942>:0 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:447   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase+<SendTokenRequestAsync>d__40.MoveNext () [0x0010e] in <4e39820fa40244d9adbc367b93b1f942>:0 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:447   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.SilentRequest+<SendTokenRequestAsync>d__4.MoveNext () [0x00164] in <4e39820fa40244d9adbc367b93b1f942>:0 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:447   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase+<RunAsync>d__33.MoveNext () [0x00360] in <4e39820fa40244d9adbc367b93b1f942>:0 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <7d5a05cfcb09432d8cc656b9d781e54b>:0   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.ClientApplicationBase+<AcquireTokenSilentCommonAsync>d__34.MoveNext () [0x000a0] in <4e39820fa40244d9adbc367b93b1f942>:0 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <7d5a05cfcb09432d8cc656b9d781e54b>:0   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.ClientApplicationBase+<AcquireTokenSilentAsync>d__31.MoveNext () [0x0007c] in <4e39820fa40244d9adbc367b93b1f942>:0 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <7d5a05cfcb09432d8cc656b9d781e54b>:0   at ApiProject.Implementations.AuthenticationService+<GetAccessTokenAsync>d__6.MoveNext () [0x00047] in C:\Projects\ProjectName\APIProject\Implementations\AuthenticationService.cs:52 }
```

**Expected Behavior**

AcquireTokenSilentAsync should always return an object with an IdToken that I can use as a bearer token for my API Requests. This should occur on both Android and iOS.

**Actual Behavior**

AcquireTokenSilentAsync is returning an object with an IdToken most of the time, but when it is on the page that doesn't always work and is on iOS, it usually returns an exception instead.

Comment: You can refer to the link https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AcquireTokenSilentAsync-using-a-cached-token

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I've tried to use that signature but my version of MSAL only accepts (IEnumerable<string> scopes, IUser user) and (IEnumerable<string> scopes, IUser user, string authority, bool forceRefresh)

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I've implemented something closer to [this implementation for MSAL.NET](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AcquireTokenSilentAsync-using-a-cached-token)